# Removing QLineEdit proxy widget from QGraphicsScene on returnPressed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyside

What I would like to do is have a QLineEdit appear in my QGraphicsView when a QGraphicsTextItem is added to the scene. The line edit is only being used to set the text of the QGraphicsItem when double-clicked and needs to be removed when the return key is pressed.

I'm having trouble getting the QLineEdit to be deleted. I've tried simply deleting it when the return key is pressed but it is still not removed. Here is the code to reproduce this behaviour:

```
class Text(QGraphicsTextItem):

    def __init__(self, text, position=QPointF(0,0), parent=None, scene=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent=parent, scene=scene)

        self.parent = parent

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)

        self.height = self.document().size().height()
        self.width = self.document().size().width()
        self.text_center = QPointF(-self.width/2, -self.height/2)

        if parent:
            self.parent_center = self.parent.boundingRect().center()
            self.scene = self.parent.scene
            self.setPos(text_center)
        else:
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            self.scene = scene
            self.setPos(position - self.text_center)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        self.Editing = True
        self.nameEdit = NameEditor(self)
        self.nameEditProxy = self.scene.addWidget(self.nameEdit)
        self.nameEditProxy.setPos(self.mapToScene(QPointF(0, 0)))


class NameEditor(QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, textItem):
        super().__init__(textItem.toPlainText())

        self.setMaximumWidth(200)
        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.selectAll()
        self.grabKeyboard()

        self.textItem = textItem

    def returnPressed(self):
        self.textItem.setPlainText(self.text())
        del self


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
    view.setScene(scene)

    text = Text("Example", position=QPointF(250, 250), scene=scene)

    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am deleting the subclassed QLineEdit via `del self` in the `returnPressed` method in this attempt. I've also tried deleting the QGraphicsProxyWidget that contains it via `del self.nameEditProxy` in the `mouseDoubleClick` method of the `Text` class.

My question is how can I delete the QLineEdit on returnPressed?

Answer (score 1):

In Qt, a simple method of removing widgets from the screen is to hide them, that is if you are not worried by that; perhaps you just want to get rid of it, otherwise use

```
myWidget.setVisible(False)
```

or

```
myWidget.hide();
```

You can reuse that widget by calling

```
myWidget.setVisible(True)
```

or

```
myWidget.show()
```

and then repositioning it anywhere you want.

Comment: Ah okay well it looks like I didn't connect the `returnPressed` signal to anything (or even thought about it...). I like the suggestion though and will comment back / edit after revising.